# how do you do symbolic differentiation on function handle?

Tags: matlab

Say if i define the following:

```
g = @(x) x/sqrt(x^2+1)
```

How do i get the derivative function for g, which i can then use to evaluate at different points?

I tried the symbolic math toolkit, and tried the following:

```
>> syms x

>> f = x/sqrt(x^2+1)

f =

x/(x^2 + 1)^(1/2)

>> diff(f)

ans =

1/(x^2 + 1)^(1/2) - x^2/(x^2 + 1)^(3/2)
```

However, i cannot figure out how to turn this into a function handle/evaluate at different points. However, i prefer doing differentiation on function_handle.

Thank you very much!

Jason

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [**matlabFunction**](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) to convert a symbolic equation to a function. For example:

```
syms x1 x2;
f1 = x1^2+x2^2;
Df1 = jacobian(f1, [x1 x2]);
Df1 = matlabFunction(Df1);
```

Then Df1(0, 0) returns [0 0] as expected.

The function [**matlabFunction**](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) was [introduced in version 5.2 (R2009a)](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/symbolic/rn/brz0m2w-1.html) of the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/symbolic/).

Comment: @jmbr: Since our answers were so similar, I just deleted mine and added its contents to yours.