# Get the derivative of a function_handle in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, derivative, function-handle

Is it possible to get the derivative of a **function_handle** as a other **function_handle**?

Like:

```
  fun1 = @(x) x^2;
  % do that ...
  disp(fun2);
    @(x) x*2
```

I know how to find the derivative of a symbolic function but I can't convert a function_handle to a symbolic function.

I'm new to matlab and I couldn't find any way on doing that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2307705/1132686

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "No." MATLAB has no idea what the contents of the function_handle mean in a symbolic sense. You're better off creating it using `syms` in first place.

A longer answer would be either to use the Symbolic Math Toolbox, as suggested by @A Danesh, or an approximation, as suggested by @Andrey.

However, if you're always working with polynomials, then you can store the coefficients as an array and use the following functions:

- `polyval` to evaluate
- `conv` to multiply
- `deconv` to divide
- `polyder` to differentiate
- `polyint` to integrate

Answer (score 1):

```
syms x 
f = @(x) x^2 + 1; 
diff(f,x)
```

Ans:

```
2*x + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get an approximation function:

```
 delta = 0.0001;
 d = @(x)( (fun1(x+delta) - fun1(x))./delta)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't analytically from a function handle.

but if you got the symbolic math toolbox you can derivate the symbolic function and create a function handle from the result.